# Framework for Augmented Reality on Android

Tags: android, frameworks, augmented-reality

I am looking for an Augmented Reality framework for Android that is location based, so i can show at specific points different information. Anyone know some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at the following link 
It may help you
http://code.google.com/p/andar/

Answer (score 2):

[DroidAR](http://code.google.com/p/droidar/) is location and marker based.

Comment: Can you help me with some pointers on how to add onclick events to the markers added for POIS using droidar. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

[Look!](http://www.lookar.net/), [LibreGeoSocial](http://www.libregeosocial.org/), [android-augment-reality-framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/) (based on Mixare) and [Android-AR-Kit](https://github.com/haseman/Android-AR-Kit/) maybe you should look. All are Open Source.

Comment: Most of Android-AR-Kit seems to be from "first commit" 3 years ago -- so I think there's not much going on there.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend Mixare - http://code.google.com/p/mixare/

Answer (score 1):

[Metaio SDK Mobile](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) has a Location-based POI visualization engine.

Answer (score 0):

[3DAR](http://www.3dar.us/) is free with branding.

Comment: 3DAR is only for iOS. i need for Android